# How can I get rsync on windows via ssh not to hang?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, rsync

I have [MobaSSH](http://mobassh.mobatek.net/en/) installed on two Windows (XP and Vista) machines. When I do rsync over ssh it often hangs. I've read this happens with cygwin/rsync/ssh (MobaSSH is cygin based). Is there any known fix or alternate ssh/rsync server I could use?

Comment: Could you point to links where you've read this being discussed? I've not heard of it happening before (I use cygwin ssh+rsync regularly) and such links might give knowledgeable people clues.

Comment: Here is one such example: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-06/msg00800.html

Comment: http://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2005-April/012190.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use rsync + ssh on Cygwin 1.7 (the beta release) and haven't encountered this problem yet.  Most of my rsync is a Windows machine pulling via rsync from a Linux machine.

There are articles out there discussing possible issues.

http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/10/14/solving-rsync-hangs-with-cygwin/ - this links to a [rsync daemon setup](http://www.alleft.com/projects/wombat/wombat-1.0/documentation.shtml)

A relatively [recent thread](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-08/msg00046.html) on the Cygwin list offers some alternatives, and again they iterate using the rsyncd.

Here's another walkthrough of setting up [rsyncd](http://www.gaztronics.net/rsync.php).

Between 2 Windows machines I've always found it easier to use Windows File Sharing to copy the files.

Comment: I ended up using rsyncd and a ssh tunnel to the port it listens on. I haven't seen any hangs with this configuration.